# Error when I try to create different BigQuery tables at the same pipeline execution

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a pipeline execution with the below code:

```
PCollection<TableRow> test1 = ...
test1
    .apply(BigQueryIO.Write
        .named("test1 write")
        .to("project_name:dataset_name.test1")
        .withSchema(tableSchema)
        .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
        .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND));

PCollection<TableRow> test2 = ...
test2
    .apply(BigQueryIO.Write
        .named("test2 write")
        .to("project_name:dataset_name.test2")
        .withSchema(tableSchema)
        .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
        .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND));
```

If I execute the pipeline and neither table "test1" nor "test2" exists, I obtain the below information:

```
jun 09, 2015 12:29:24 PM com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.BigQueryTableInserter tryCreateTable
INFORMACIÓN: Trying to create BigQuery table: project_name:dataset_name.test1
jun 09, 2015 12:29:27 PM com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.RetryHttpRequestInitializer$LoggingHttpBackoffUnsuccessfulResponseHandler handleResponse
ADVERTENCIA: Request failed with code 404, will NOT retry: https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/pragmatic-armor-455/datasets/audit/tables/project_name:dataset_name.test2/insertAll
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
{
  "code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Not found: Table project_name:dataset_name.test2",
    "reason" : "notFound"
  } ],
  "message" : "Not found: Table project_name:dataset_name.test2"
}
```

Why only the first table is created?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble we are investigating.

Comment: Do you get this error running on the service, locally, or both?

Comment: I get this error running either locally or at cloud.

Comment: Is this a streaming or batch job? Could you please share the job id of one of the failed jobs? You can also email it to us privately at dataflow-feedback@google.com.

Comment: Ok Jeremy. I've sent the email to dataflow-feedback@google.com.

Comment: A bug has been identified in BigQueryIO that causes only 1 table to be created in streaming jobs in which multiple tables have the same schema. A  fix is forthcoming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. The cause was a bug in BigQueryIO that caused the second table to occasionally not be created. This bug has now been fixed in github with [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/commit/c3c9e6a65a2ba645e7dfdbfc8d335e4090c910d7) commit. The fix will be pushed to maven later this month. Sorry for the trouble!